# how to update a directory that is a mirror of another one (with hard-links)?

Tags: linux, cp

I like using `cp -rl dir1 dir2` to make a recursive copy of `dir1` into `dir2` (using hard links to save storage, and usually followed by `rsync` to make progressive backups).

The issue is that, if `dir2` already exists, then the command above will simply create the copy *under it* (`dir2/dir1`).  Sometimes I'd like to just update an existing `dir2` and bring it up to perfect sync with `dir1`.  Of course, I could first kick `dir2` out of the way first, i.e.:

```
 rm -rf dir2
 cp -rl dir1 dir2
```

But that strikes me as wasteful.  Is there a way to use `cp` and/or `rsync` to update the destination (and remove extra stuff) so as to efficiently achieve the result of the two lines above?

Comment: What is the reason why you don't want to use rsync for this, since it obviously does what you want?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling interesting idea, but what would be the actual options to use to implement the desired effect?  Remember I want hard-links wherever possible, and from a content perspective an absolute mirror.

Comment: If you are willing to accept answers that do not involve the use of `cp` specifically, then you should edit the question to reflect that fact. (Answers on Stack Exchange should, generally speaking, answer the question as asked; meaning if you ask for `cp` answers only, then that's what you'll get.) In that case, it might be better to omit the mention of cp completely, or use it only as an example to demonstrate the behavior you want. That said, rsync's `-a --link-dest=...` switch combination seems like a good place to start, but see the man page for details on both of those switches.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: fair enough. I was focusing on `cp` but indeed it's a certain behavior (and some efficiency) that I'm looking for. Question edited to reflect that.